# Dealing with huge amount of select statements

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

i'm designing an ASP.NET Application wich builds an Overview of all the sales per partner in a period of time.
How it works so far:

1. Select all partnerNo(SQL-Server) and add to List(ASP.NET)
2. Select sales of partnerNo1 over period of time(SQL-Server), summarize them(ASP.NET) and add them to a DataTable(ASP.NET)
3. Select sales of partnerNo2 over period of time, summarize them and add them to a datatable
4. Select sales of partnerNo3 over period of time, summarize them and add them to a datatable

and so on

Now here is the Problem: if i select only the TOP 100 partnerNo, if takes a while, but i get a result. If i change the TOP to 1000, the SQL-Server processes the SQL-Statements
(can see him working in activitymonitor), and the iis-server is feeding him the new SQL-Selects... but after a while, the iis is terminating the page-request from the browser, so no result is shown

i really hope, i could explain it enough for someone to help me.

With regards

Dirk Th.

Comment: Which framework version are you using?

Comment: Another option might be to look into Microsoft SQL Server Analysis Services (SSAS) if you want to generate summarized data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the [RBAR anti-pattern](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/rbar--row-by-agonizing-row/).  It should be possible to create one SQL query that returns summarized information from all partners.

That's typically much faster: less data has to go over the line, and less often.  A roundtrip to a database can cost 50ms.  If you do 600 of those, you're at the 30 second timeout for web pages.

Comment: the Problem is not the summarizing, it's the data themself... i have to do calculations from columns, which i don't want to show in the results... something like this:
`dr["umsVJ"] = (Convert.ToDecimal(dr["wertNettoTotal"]) != 0 && Convert.ToDecimal(dr["wertNettoTotalVJ"]) != 0) ? ((Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(dr["wertNettoTotal"]) * 100 / Convert.ToDecimal(dr["wertNettoTotalVJ"]), 2) - 100).ToString()) : ((Convert.ToDecimal(dr["wertNettoTotal"]) == 0) ? ((Convert.ToDecimal(dr["roherloesVJ"]) > 0) ? "-100" : "0") : ((Convert.ToDecimal(dr["roherloesVJ"]) == 0) ? "100" : "0"));`

Comment: Looks like something you could do in SQL with a bit of effort

Comment: I played a bit with it, and it seems, it's really the sheer amount of selects, that's slowing everything down... well, my boss won't like it, we have to change all the code, but hey, better this than don't get any result. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Framework 4.5, AND getting the summary data for each partnerN is mutually exclusive, you can try parallel tasks.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460720.aspx

Now, that's not a simple subject.  But it would allow you to take advantage of multiple processors.

Number one rule.  You CANNOT RELY ON SEQUENCE.

........

Option 2, a more "traditional" approach is to hit the database for everything you need.
I would abandon DataTables, and start using DTO or POCO objects.

Then you can author mini "read only properties" that replace your calculated/derived data-table columns.

Go to the database, do not use cursors or looping, and hit the database for all the info you need.  After you get it back, stuff it into DTOs/POCO's rely on read-only properties where you can (for derived values)..........and then if you have to run some business logic to figure-out some derived values, then do that.

If you're "stuck" with a DataSet/DataTable for the presentation layer, you can do loop over your DTOs/POCOs and stuff them into a DataSet/DataTable.

Comment: "Go to the database, do not use cursors or looping, and hit the database for all the info you need."......this is the opposite of the RBAR pattern that Andomar mentioned.  Row by Row will slow you down.